# Generating Finite Vector Space over Finite Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-fields

A  question led me into this question:

Does there exist a vector space which exactly have 8 elements?

Now, after some initial research, I found there did exist such vector space, and as long as the cardinality is a power of prime, we can always found such vector space.

Actually there is a well-established result: for a finite field $K$ with $p^n$, it can always be treated as a Vector Space over $F_{p}$.

Now it occurs me to me: does every vector space has cardinality of $p^n$?

Comment: @MorganRodgers I have rephrased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A $d$-dimensional vector space over a finite field with $q$ elements has size $q^d$. Since finite fields only occur with prime powers: $q = p^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and so the finite vector space has $(p^n)^d = p^{nd}$ elements.

There are only a couple ways to write $8$ as a power of a prime power:
\begin{align*}
8 = (2^1)^3 
\qquad &\Longrightarrow \qquad 
V \cong (\mathbb{F}_2)^3 
\text{ is $3$-dim over field with $2$ elements} \\
8 = (2^3)^1 
\qquad &\Longrightarrow \qquad 
V \cong (\mathbb{F}_{2^3})^1 
\text{ is $1$-dim over field with $8 = 2^3$ elements}
\end{align*}

But, seeing as how the field $\mathbb{F}_{2^3}$ is itself a $3$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$, the second construction is essentially the same as the first (you have to "forget" the multiplication inside the bigger field, as vectors don't multiply in a vector space).

Answer (score 2):

A finite vector space  $V$ is necessarily either 0-dimensional (i.e., has only one vector, $0$) or is over some finite field $\Bbb F_{p^m}$ and finite-dimensional. If $e_1,\ldots, e_d$ is a basis, then $V$ consists precisely of all $\sum_{i=1}^dc_ie_i$ with $c_i\in \Bbb F_{p^m}$. We count $$|V|=(p^m)^d=p^{md}.$$